# How can we add groupby taking inputs from the user from the table we have uploaded?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to take input from the user for group_by and count of the data on the columns selected by the user from the uploaded CSV file. In short, the user should select the columns he needs to group_by and getting the count of the data

I am able to upload the file and getting the summary in the load section, I have created a prep column for this group_by part.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

ui<-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Model"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("Data", tabName = "data", icon =       icon("table"),startExpanded = TRUE,
                         menuSubItem("Load", tabName = "data1"),
                         menuSubItem("Prep", tabName = "prep")
                ),
                menuItem("Visualisation",icon=icon("bar-chart-o"),   tabName = "vis"),
                menuItem("Result", icon=icon("cog"), tabName =  "result")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(type="text/css",
               ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
               ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
    ),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "data1",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                 fileInput("file1","Choose CSV File",
                           accept = c("text/csv",
                                   "text/comma-seperated-values, text/plain",
                                   ".csv")
              ),
                  tags$hr(),
                checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
              radioButtons("sep","Separator",
                           choices=c(Comma=",",
                                     semicolon=";",
                                     Tab="\t"),
                           selected = ";")
            ),
            mainPanel(
              uiOutput("tb")
            )
          )
     )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "prep",
           fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            mainPanel(
              uiOutput("Pre")
            )
          )
        ))
  )
   )


  server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
  data <- reactive({
  file1 <- input$file1
   if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    read.csv(file = file1$datapath, sep=input$sep)
 })

  output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
    input$file1
     })
   output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
   summary(data())
   })
   output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
    data()
   })
   output$tb <- renderUI({
   if(is.null(data())){return()}
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file",     tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data",                  tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))

  })

  #----- Data Preparation------
  output$Pre <- renderUI({checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "select_vars",
                                             label="Select Variables",
                                            choices = names(filedf))

  })
  filedf_sel <- reactive({
    req(input$select_vars)
    filedf_sel<- data()%>% select(input$select_var)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

the output should be the result of the group_by and count on the columns selected by the user

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a place for user to choose the columns. As you're using user data for it, `?renderUI` seems like an OK option for me. Something like this should do:

```
output$group_by_selection <- renderUI({
  req(data())
  selectizeInput(
        'group_by_select', 'Group by', choices = colnames(data()), multiple = TRUE
      ),
```

It should be in the `server.R` file. Use `uiOutput('group_by_selection')` in `ui.R` to show it.

Now, you need to group and count the data after user is done selecting. You can do it by button press or whatever. It can look like this, using `data.table` library for easy grouping and counting:

```
grouped_data <- eventReactive(input$group_by_button, {
  if (length(input$group_by_select) > 0 ) {
    data()[, Count := .N, by = input$group_by_select]
  } else {
    NULL 
  }
})
```

Comment: it is only showing the column names to select but not showing actual results for that groupby

Comment: also, its its showing column names appearing on the front page only, we are not able to see the other columns

Comment: can u please help?

Comment: I'm trying to. After you selected a column, you need to run the piece of code that will count the data or whatever you need to do with it. You can do it in different ways, which part of my suggestion isn't working? You need to add a button that will run the 'grouping by' code, and part of code that will be executed when the button is pressed.. That part is present in my snippet. I'm not going to write everything for you.